# Issue regarding convert numeric value to 24 hrs format time

Tags: c#, string, datetime, format

I was trying to convert a numeric value to 24 hours format time but the code is not working. Here is my code:

```
string xx = 
    Convert.ToDateTime(TimeSpan.FromHours(01).ToString())
           .ToString("HH", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

OR

string xx1 = 
    new DateTime(TimeSpan.FromHours(01).Ticks)
    .ToString("HH", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

OR

var t = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
string xx2 =new DateTime(t.Ticks).ToString("hh:mm:ss tt");

OR

string ss = TimeSpan.FromHours(01).ToString("HH");
```

The above code is not working. I searched Google and everyone said use `HH` for getting hour in 24 hours format. Can anyone tell me if this is specific issue to my PC?

Comment: What do you mean by _not working_? You get any exception or error message? Can you please be more specific? What is your numeric value?

Comment: getting no error rather first line of code return 01 instead of 13.

Comment: How do you know that the 01 is PM instead of AM?

Comment: @juharr Because OP try to parse 1 hour without date part, `Convert.ToDateTime` parse it as today's date and `01:00:00` as an hour. It will be `13/01/2015 01:00:00` at the end and since it's hour part before `12:00:00`, it will be `1 AM` not `1 PM`

Comment: @SonerGönül I know that.  I'm asking the OP how they know that the 01 they are starting with should be PM instead of AM.  Basically if you have a numeric value in the 12-hour format you have to know if it is AM or PM to convert to 24-hour format, and it's as simple as adding 12.

Comment: before i was trying to convert 01 to 24hrs format which is not possible because 01 could be AM or PM. so tell me can we convert `01 PM to 13 -- 24 hrs format` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> getting no error rather first line of code return 01 instead of 13.

Because you adding `1` hour from midnight. You should add `13` hour instead like;

```
string xx = Convert.ToDateTime(TimeSpan.FromHours(13).ToString())
           .ToString("HH", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Since [`TimeSpan.FromHours(01).ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromhours%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns `01:00:00` as a `string`, [`Convert.ToDateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.todatetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) parse this string as `13/01/2015 01:00:00`<sup>1</sup>.

And [24-hour clock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock) representation of a `01` will be the same as itself no matter you use `hh` or `HH` specifier.

On your second example, you calculate your `TimeSpan` as a [`Ticks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`DateTime(Int64)` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2xf7zzk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  calculates this time from `01/01/0001` and your `DateTime` evantually will be `01/01/0001 01:00:00` and still, it's 24-hour clock representation will be `01`.

On your third example, you are calling `DateTime(Int64)` constructor with [`TimeOfDay` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), that's why your DateTime will be `01.01.0001 15:10:36` (when I run your example right now) and it's `hh:mm:ss tt` representation will be `03:11:31 PM` in [`InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Your fourth line throws [`FormatException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.formatexception.aspx) because there is no [standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [custom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) `HH` format specifier of a `TimeSpan`.

**1**: <sup>Since you parse only hour without date, this method returns date part as a today</sup>

Comment: before i was trying to convert 01 to 24hrs format which is not possible because 01 could be AM or PM. so tell me can we convert 01 PM to 13 -- 24 hrs format ?

Comment: @Mou `01 PM` is just a string representation of a `DateTime` which has `13:00:00` as a hour part. If you wanna string represention as `01 PM` of your `DateTime`, you can use `yourDateTime.ToString("HH tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`. If you want to parse your `01 PM` string to `DateTime`, you can use custom date parsing like `DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("01 PM", "HH tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: Sorry, the last code should be `DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("01 PM", "hh tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` since `01 PM` is 12-hour format.

Comment: if i code this way `DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("01 PM", "HH tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` then does it return 13 ?

Comment: @Mou Read my second [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27922301/issue-regarding-convert-numeric-value-to-24-hrs-format-time/27922395?noredirect=1#comment44273103_27922395). This code throws exception with `HH` specifier because input string is 12-hour format. But when you parse it with `hh`, you can get `13` as a result if you get string representation of your `dt` like; `dt.ToString("HH");`.

Comment: yes your are right. this line works i tested `DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("01PM", "hht", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            string pp22 = dt.Hour.ToString();`